# Refresh function per 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

```
function random_imglink() {
    var myimages = new Array()
        //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1] = "This is text1."
    myimages[2] = "This is text2."
    myimages[3] = "This is text3."
    myimages[4] = "This is text4."
    myimages[5] = "This is text5."
    myimages[6] = "This is text6."

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length)
    if (ry == 0)
        ry = 1
    document.write('<h1 class="comingsoon">' + myimages[ry] + '</h1>')
}
random_imglink()
```

How do you make it so that the above code gets refreshed every 3 seconds? Like, the output is refreshed every 3 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: Use setInterval function of javascript here is the tutorial and demo http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @Amit the result is shown as http://i.imgur.com/k3kPK81.png. I have tried using setinterval but not to what I'm expecting. Is the document.write code correct? Please check.

Comment: @youdoreallysay first clarify what your expected result is..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a fiddle that I think does what you want.

I hope you like cats.

http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/9cu5L666/

Note - I'm setting the inner html of a div, rather than the whole document

```
function random_imglink() {

    var myimages = new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1] = "http://placekitten.com/g/100/400"
    myimages[2] = "http://placekitten.com/g/200/250"
    myimages[3] = "http://placekitten.com/g/300/234"
    myimages[4] = "http://placekitten.com/g/500/300"
    myimages[5] = "http://placekitten.com/g/100/400"
    myimages[6] = "http://placekitten.com/g/430/100"

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length)
    if (ry == 0)
        ry = 1;

    var div = document.getElementById('myContainer');
    div.innerHTML='<h1 class="comingsoon"><img src="' + myimages[ry] + '"</img></h1>'
}
setInterval(function(){ random_imglink(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the last 3rd/4th line! I pretty much figured it out myself thanks to those lines of yours ^_^

Comment: I knew the cats would help... ;-)

Comment: It sure did  ^_^ When I leave the page on for a minute, the text starts to change like crazy. Like, it doesn't change every 3 seconds and starts to change every 1 milisecond? Is it a normal bug in JS or..?

Comment: hmm, it's probably best to create a separate question about this.. and include a jsfiddle showing the problem... i'm not sure off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is easier way for your query.

Simple Example:

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: It doesn't work like I expect it to be. I want a text in the middle of the page to be refreshed every 3 seconds, I've tried using setInterval like you said but it doesn't follow the CSS rules and completely creates a new page with said text.

Comment: @youdoreallysay yeah that's because you are showing your text by using `document.write()` don't use it if you want to show inside a `DOM`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write`. Use `document.innerHTML` instead.

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

And of course the `setInterval`, as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval`

```
window.setInterval(random_imglink,3000);
```

Comment: the result is shown as http://i.imgur.com/k3kPK81.png. I have tried using setinterval but not to what I'm expecting. Is the document.write code correct? Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.setInterval(random_imglink, 3000);
```

but be cautious because if your browser does not render the content in the time interval you should expect choppiness and dropped frames. A much better approach is to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

> The Window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you
>   wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a
>   specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. The
>   method takes as an argument a callback to be invoked before the
>   repaint.

```
function random_imglink() {
    var myimages = new Array()
        //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1] = "This is text1."
    myimages[2] = "This is text2."
    myimages[3] = "This is text3."
    myimages[4] = "This is text4."
    myimages[5] = "This is text5."
    myimages[6] = "This is text6."

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length)
    if (ry == 0)
        ry = 1
    document.body.innerHTML = '<h1 class="comingsoon">' + myimages[ry] + '</h1>';
}


window.setInterval(random_imglink, 3000);
```

Comment: the result is shown as http://i.imgur.com/k3kPK81.png. I have tried using setinterval as you mentioned but not to what I'm expecting. Is the document.write code correct? Please check.